# Yahoo pipes guru help to extract a string and output correctly

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I would like to extract a date which is a string in item.description and the output it as `item.date`?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Pull out a loop and put a string regex inside it.
- Choose item.description and assign results to date
- What you put in the replace box depends on the format of your date.

> ```
> For dates like this:
> 01/01/10
> you would put .*(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2}).*
> For dates like this:
> 01-01-2010
> you would put .*(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4}).*
> ```

- in the with box put $1/$2/$3

Comment: waoo thank you sir.
2 horrible things 

1/ is that the date are pulled from different feeds in different formats thank you rss..

2/ is that my feeds are pulled from feed43 and seems not to be correctly pulled in yahoo pipes...
--> that is the main problem if anyone has encountered this ?

TY for your time and sharing knowledge anyway this permit me to learn more ;)

Comment: there is a more general regex that will accept either format: .*(\d{2})[/-](\d{2})[/-](\d{2,4}).* Don't forget to choose my answer.

Comment: OMG, you have no idea how long I searched for this... Just that first line, "Pull out a loop and put a string regex inside it", made everything click. Thank you!